# Comparing two groups with different size on multiple continuous variables

Tags: multiple-comparisons, manova

I want to compare two groups on 9 continuous variables to see whether mean scores on these variables differ between the two groups. However, my samples have a very different size: one group includes 299 participants, the other group 45.

I performed a MANOVA with the continuous variables as 'dependents' and group membership as 'fixed factor'. I wonder whether I should control for multiple testing in this case? And if so, what is the best way to do this using spss?

Also, the two groups differ on a number of demographic characteristics (all categorical: gender, age, education level), it seems to me that I should check whether the difference I find between the two groups on the continuous variables is not influenced by the difference between the groups in demographic characteristics. But can I do this using MANOVA or would it then be better to perform a regression analysis, and to include the relevant demographic characteristics in a second block?

Comment: The second part is different, and you might want to remove it from here and ask as a separate question. Briefly, if all your covariates (demographic characteristics) are categorical then you will have a factorial MANOVA. But note that with sample size of 45 you don't have a lot of data to split it by gender/age/education etc., so you might not have enough data to control for all your covariates. And by the way, MANOVA *is* a regression analysis.